# How to add space to String in Json file using jq

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have the following JSON File:

```
{ 
    "releases": [
                {
                  "name": "bpm",
                  "version": "1.1.5"
                },
                {
                  "name": "haproxy",
                  "version": "9.8.0"
                }
              ]
    }
```

I am trying to extract the name and version so i get the following:

```
bpm 1.1.5
haproxy 9.8.0
```

I have used the following query:

```
jq -r '.releases [] | .name + \() + .version' release_info.json
```

But the space is not added and i get an error.

How is it possible to add a space?

Comment: @Shawn Let's assume, though (given the query), that it's just a snippet from a larger, valid JSON file.

Comment: @Shawn i have corrected the JSON file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.name + " " + .version
```

or

```
"\(.name) \(.version)"
```